# Is there a way to delete call logs and SMS programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, sms

I want the ability for a user to specify a time-frame and delete all call logs and sms created during that time-frame. Does Apple allow this functionality?

I know this is like accessing the sandbox mode of a private app but just want to confirm if there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, There is no way to access the SMS or Call Logs.

Apple encourages third party apps to be developed to carry unique functions. Not the ones that are already available from First party which is apple itself.

Call log and sms are synced to iCloud. So i guess even if you figure out a way to access them using some private api, you might not be able to update them. so apparently they will be resynched.